# Struct will not conform with equatable, even with == set

Tags: swift

I'm using a switch statement to go through a bunch of MenuItems.  I am getting a warning on each case:

> Operator function '~=' requires that 'MenuItem' conform to 'Equatable'

I thought I knew what that error meant, but this is the code for MenuItem:

```
struct MenuItem {
    let image: UIImage
    let title: String
    let body: String
    let storyboardName: String
    let storyboardID: String
    let landingItems: [LandingItem]

    static func == (lhs: MenuItem, rhs: MenuItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.storyboardID == rhs.storyboardID
    }
}


struct LandingItem {
    let image: UIImage
    let title: String
    let body: String
    let storyboardName: String
    let storyboardID: String

    static func == (lhs: LandingItem, rhs: LandingItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.storyboardID == rhs.storyboardID
    }
}
```

Is there some way to make MenuItem uh ... Super Equatable?  Or am I missing something else really obvious?

Comment: If I replace LandingItem with String, the code compiles. What is LandingItem?

Comment: @GeneZ.Ragan Added!

Comment: extend your structs from Equatable

Comment: @Ildar.Z d'oh . Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift’s typesafety is very strict. Even if you implement == it doest count unless you state conformity to the Equateable protocol.

```
struct MenuItem: Equatable {
    let image: UIImage
    let title: String
    let body: String
    let storyboardName: String
    let storyboardID: String
    let landingItems: [LandingItem]

    static func == (lhs: MenuItem, rhs: MenuItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.storyboardID == rhs.storyboardID
    }
}

struct LandingItem: Equatable {
    let image: UIImage
    let title: String
    let body: String
    let storyboardName: String
    let storyboardID: String

    static func == (lhs: LandingItem, rhs: LandingItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.storyboardID == rhs.storyboardID
    }
}
```

Comment: so, tl;dr: it was something obvious.  Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome. @Ildar.Z: Thank you for the edit. Typing answers on a phone is not that comfy.